# Como saber si una fecha se acerca a mi fecha actual php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Muy buenas a todos,estoy trabajando en notificaciones y estaba intentando hacer una condicional sobre si la fecha de registro se esta acercando a la fecha de hoy.
Lo estaba intentando de esta manera

```
  <?php $fecha_hoy = date('Y-m-d'); ?>
        <?php $fecha_registro = date($c->fechacita, strtotime('-1 days')); ?>
```

Comment: Imagino necesitas saber evaluar si ya está dentro de un rango de X días o horas antes, cierto?

Comment: un rango de días, por ejemplo 2022-07-27 le faltan 2 dias para estar igual a 2022-07-29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que el formato de las fechas con el que trabajas es `Y-m-d`

Tienes estas dos funciones :

```php
function sumarDias($fecha,$numero) {
        list($ano,$mes,$dia) = preg_split("/-/",$fecha);
        return (date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,$mes,$dia+$numero,$ano)));
    }

function restarDias($fecha,$numero) {
        list($ano,$mes,$dia) = preg_split("/-/",$fecha);
        return(date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,$mes,$dia-$numero,$ano)));
    }
```

**Como funciona ?**

- Obtener los registros dos días antes

```php
//Obtienes las fecha actual

$fecha = date("Y-m-d");

//le restas `2  dias`  

$fecha = restarDias($fecha,2)


//buscas en tu tabla 

select * from t_mitabla where fecha = '$fecha'
```

- Obtener los registros dos días después

```php
    //Obtienes las fecha actual

    $fecha = date("Y-m-d");

    //le restas `2  dias`  

    $fecha = sumarDias($fecha,2)


    //buscas en tu tabla 

    select * from t_mitabla where fecha = '$fecha'
```